# Change facebook application on custom policies azure b2c

Tags: facebook, azure-ad-b2c

Our client wanted to change the Facebook application on our b2c tenant. I updated the custom policy but when a user logs in with his Facebook account that is already registered in our tenant it creates e new object-id on b2c. 
Is there a way to update de facebook application(client id and secret) on my custom policy and avoid the Facebook users to generate new object ids on my tenant?

Answer (score 0):

In your updated Facebook-OAUTH TechnicalProfile, did you happen to use a different DefaultValue for the identityProvider OutputClaim? If that value is different, the alternativeSecurityId claim that is generated for Facebook user will be different as well, resulting in a new directory user.

If you follow the logic of the CreateAlternativeSecurityId output claims transformation, you'll that it ends up using the [CreateAlternativeSecurityId TransformationMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations#createalternativesecurityid) 
to build the alternativeSecurityId claim, so you get something like this.

```
{ "issuer": "facebook.com", "issuerUserId": "MTA4MTQ2MDgyOTI3MDUyNTYzMjcw"}
```

That alternativeSecurityId claim is used later in your SignUpOrSignIn UserJourney to read an existing user from the directory. If it can't find a user with the same generated alternativeSecurityId, it will write a new user with that ID.

If query the AAD Graph API for your Facebook users, you should see that they have different values (a different issuer) for [userIdentities property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) where the collection of alternativeSecurityId claims from B2C are stored for a user.